# Add minutes from a column to timestamp in another column pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have the below dataframe.

```
Date       time      additional_time(in mins)
2021-02-01 12:02:05  60
2021-02-10 09:00:00  30
```

I have to combine the date and time column using concat_ws with spaces as concatenation and then add the additional time as minutes to the timestamp.

Expected output:

```
Timestamp
2021-02-01 13:02:05
2021-02-10 09:30:00
```

Interval in minutes can be used if I have to add a constant time to all rows. But in my condition the time to be added varies for every row.

Kindly let me know how to achieve this in Pyspark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say `df` is your dataframe

```
data = [["2021-02-01", "12:02:05",  60],
        ["2021-02-10", "09:00:00",  30]]
schema = "Date:string,time:string,`additional_time(in mins)`:int"

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show()

# +----------+--------+------------------------+
# |      Date|    time|additional_time(in mins)|
# +----------+--------+------------------------+
# |2021-02-01|12:02:05|                      60|
# |2021-02-10|09:00:00|                      30|
# +----------+--------+------------------------+
```

You can utilize `unix_timestamp` to get the unix epoch of the datetime, add with *additional_time(in mins)* in second, then revert it back using `from_unixtime`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("timestamp", F.expr("from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat_ws(' ', date, time)) + (`additional_time(in mins)` * 60))"))
df.show()

# +----------+--------+------------------------+-------------------+
# |      Date|    time|additional_time(in mins)|          timestamp|
# +----------+--------+------------------------+-------------------+
# |2021-02-01|12:02:05|                      60|2021-02-01 13:02:05|
# |2021-02-10|09:00:00|                      30|2021-02-10 09:30:00|
# +----------+--------+------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Just did it using Unix timestamp. Thank you